# Accessing "Process Info" via an app

Tags: sql-server, process

I am working with sql 2000

I am trying to access all of the "current activity>process info" from microsoft access. I thought, the sproc code in the link below would give me it but it doesnt. I have no problem basing a dataset on sp_lock2 and reading the info, but it doesnt pull all of the data in the process info view under enterprise manager.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255596

I am new to sql server, but have a few years exp as an access/ excel developer..

any help is much appreciated..

i have already posted this on sqlteam. please reply on the sqlteam thread:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=119037

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this?

```
exec sp_who2
```